# How to make a dash "–" on a US International keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Reference: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halbgeviertstrich

Note that the en dash "–" is longer than the hyphen-minus "-". I am interested in how to type the former on a US International keyboard layout. Looking forward to your tips!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash - how to type it depends on the OS you're using; so which is it? What you're looking for is probably Unicode 2014, the Em-dash. Unicode 2010 to 2015 are a collection of slightly different length dashes.

Comment: OP's is actually an n-dash [en dash U+2013] I've added the correct unicode names to the question. Link to English wiki page, though idk how well the content matches the German - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Answer (score 1):

*If* you use Windows, *and* you have a numeric keypad on your keyboard, then you can hold the left Alt key, type 0150 (short ndash –) or 0151 (long mdash —) on the numeric keypad, and then release the Alt key again.

This should work on any keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, n– & m— dash are all on the same key, with different modifiers.

<kbd>-</kbd>   gives the regular hyphen-minus `-`

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>  gives an n-dash `–`

<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>  gives an m-dash `—`